# Getting location while app is terminated in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have been working on a location-oriented project that I need to be able to track a user's location while the app is terminated.

I have a [background service](https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/BackgroundLocationDemo) in my Android project and the [Geolocator Plugin](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/BackgroundUpdates.html).

Just for reference, here are my Geolocator settings:

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public static async void StartListening()
{
    if (CrossGeolocator.Current.IsListening)
        return;

    CrossGeolocator.Current.DesiredAccuracy = 10;

    await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(LOCATION_PING_SECONDS), 1, true, new Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ListenerSettings
    {
        AllowBackgroundUpdates = true,
        PauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    });

    CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += PositionChanged;
    CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionError += PositionError;
}
```

This + my location service for Android work like a charm while the app is running and backgrounded, but obviously everything stops when the app is terminated.

**Android/MainActivity.cs**

```
public void StartLocationService()
{
    powerManager = (PowerManager) GetSystemService(PowerService);
    wakeLock = powerManager.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Full, "LocationHelper");

    // create a new service connection so we can get a binder to the service
    locationServiceConnection = new LocationServiceConnection(null);

    // this event will fire when the Service connectin in the OnServiceConnected call 
    locationServiceConnection.ServiceConnected += (object sender, ServiceConnectedEventArgs e) => {

        Console.WriteLine("Service Connected");
    };

    // Starting a service like this is blocking, so we want to do it on a background thread
    new Task(() => {

        // Start our main service
        Console.WriteLine("App", "Calling StartService");
        Android.App.Application.Context.StartService(new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(LocationService)));

        // bind our service (Android goes and finds the running service by type, and puts a reference
        // on the binder to that service)
        // The Intent tells the OS where to find our Service (the Context) and the Type of Service
        // we're looking for (LocationService)
        Intent locationServiceIntent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(LocationService));
        Console.WriteLine("App", "Calling service binding");

        // Finally, we can bind to the Service using our Intent and the ServiceConnection we
        // created in a previous step.
        Android.App.Application.Context.BindService(locationServiceIntent, locationServiceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);
    }).Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Aquiring Wake Lock");

    wakeLock.Acquire();
}
```

Does anyone know of any tutorials for getting location updates even when the app is terminated? Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Also, I found this [Xamarin forum post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/90797/background-task-even-when-the-app-is-closed)... The last post says he is able to get updates while the app is terminated from a service, but I have not been able to get the same outcome.